# Internet Explorer opening PDF's in Reader, not browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer, href

I'm working on a web design project and I'm finding one problem when I load the web page in IE.

This is a link I'm using and when I load in Chrome/Firefox and click the link, it opens in a new tab as expected. But when I click it in IE it opens it in the Windows Reader. Is there a way to set IE to open it in a new tab liek the others?

thanks

Comment: did you check addons setting? https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html

Comment: Yes but after folloeing those instructions Adobe PDF Reader doesn't appear in the list of add-ons

Comment: Try to update/repair adobe reader. Here are some advices to fix the problem - https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/quick-fix-view-pdfs-web.html

Comment: they didn't seem to work,option to chnage pdfs still not showing in manage add ons :(

Comment: Could you please add a pdf file link to problem description? What is IE version? Maybe screenshot of addons panel will help.

Comment: <a href="links/abc.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="img/abcd.jpg" height="210" width="180"></a> is the code.......its IE11

Comment: i do have a few recent windows updates to install,could that be it?

Comment: Depends on what these updates are.

Comment: I dont have adobe installed,it's the windows reader i have. Should that just have the same name in manage add ons or would it be caslled something different?

Comment: Install adobe reader, and it will appear in IE addons list.

Comment: is there a way to do it without adobe? So id want to disable windows reader and open it in the browser.